# Cortana commands only work when spoken

Tags: windows-10, cortana

After much frustration I have realized that Cortana voice commands only seem to be recognized when they are spoken and not when typed with the keyboard. For example, after installing the [CortanaVoiceCommand](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand) sample project I can say "Adventure Works show my trip to London" and it works. However, if I type in the exact same phrase the command isn't recognized and instead it searches Bing.

Is there a way to have Cortana recognize both voice *and* manually typed commands?

Comment: Have you tried Writing AdventureWorks together? and what version of the Sample are you using?
I wrote a App based on a earlier sample and can activate Cortana by just typing but I am also unable to use typing with the newest  version.

Comment: I tried it as one word, with and without commas. I am using the latest version "Windows 10 RTM Release - September 2015 Update 2." I'll check diffs later today and see if something changed that may have broken it.

Comment: Have you updated the Sample recently? We recently made a change to move from the CommandPrefix tag to the AppName tag for the CommandSet, and to remove the comma. I believe there may be some improvements to the behavior in here in newer builds of windows that have been released to insiders as well. You might want to update the sample and take a look at the updated VCD file it includes

Comment: @AndrewPilley-MSFT I had the opposite experience I have a Older Sample I used to Build a App from and I was able to Type, but with the recently updated version I had issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running a few tests here, this is possibly happening because you're using an older legacy tag (The documentation and sample accidentally uses `<CommandPrefix>` instead of `<AppName>` and includes a comma, which you should leave out.)

If you make a VCD that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="AdventureWorksCommandSet_en-us">
    <AppName> Adventure Works</AppName>
    <Example> Show trip to London </Example>

    <Command Name="showTripToDestination">
      <Example> Show trip to London </Example>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> show [my] trip to {destination} </ListenFor>
   ...
```

Your keyboard input scenario should work better, and voice will be more accurate as well. The `<CommandPrefix>` tag is a legacy tag that was accidentally included in the samples when it was built originally.

Comment: If I use your Code I can't Type and get a response but If I use the <CommandPrefix> I can.

Comment: Curious. I've got the same installed in a VM here and when typing "Adventure works when is my trip to London" it works fine. Prior to this, using a CommandPrefix block combined with the comma caused several issues due to Cortana falling back to a legacy parser that's less flexible.

Comment: Good to know, so it would be recommended to use AppName. It is strange that it doesn't work for me. Pleas keep us Updated if you find the issue. I would prefer using the new parser but I find the ability to type to communicate with Cortana essential.
If it makes a difference I am using the stable Summer release with all Updates.

Comment: Well it is working for me now. Not sure if it has anything to do with CommandPrefix or AppName since they both seem to work now. Maybe it was an old version of something or a temporary fluke with Cortana.